# Using rules from Heroes of Horror does Fearsome Necromancy stack?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, fear

*Heroes of Horror* provides rules for fear stacking from different sources.

If a spellcaster has the feat Fearsome Necromancy is each spell he uses with this benefit considered a different effect or is this only one "source" of effect?

Comment: ([The core rules provide rules for fear stacking, too.](http://dndsrd.net/abilitiesAndConditions.html#fear))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I would say that the source of fear in that case remains Fearsome Necromancy: it does not say that it adds a fear effect to the spell, but rather just says that creatures failing saves to your Necromancy spells are also shaken—as an effect of the feat itself.

However, that’s entirely irrelevant because Fearsome Necromancy explicitly states that it cannot stack with any other effect. If you rule that Fearsome Necromancy applied to different spells makes them different sources of fear, then they *still* don’t stack thanks to that rule.